# 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll in Task

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

I'm building a Winform application and i want to update a TreeView that represents a directory tree. This method takes one or two seconds, so i want to run it in parallel.

Firstly i use a Task.Factory.StartNew() with this code bellow, but i received the error `'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll in Task`.

```
Task loadTreeViewTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try {
                directoryTreeView.Nodes.Clear();
                ....
                PopulateTreeView(directory, directoryTreeView.Nodes[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
               //Log
               //Change try/catch to CancellationToken
            }
        });
```

Then i saw that Windows works with a single thread UI, and i found that i need to use InvokeRequired:

```
directoryTreeView.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
{
  try {
    directoryTreeView.Nodes.Clear();
    ....
    PopulateTreeView(directory, directoryTreeView.Nodes[0]);
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
   //Log
   //Change try/catch to CancellationToken
  }
}));
```

There is a better way to do this?

Comment: Things get worst when you write a model class that works harder in the background and eventually calls its own events on certain checkpoints. You absolutely don't know how events will be used. If happens that someone use an event in order to update a view, you get stuck in the same awkward situation. You are doing things apparently right. The other end is also using events correctly, but your model is thread-based and bigbang happens...

Answer (score 2):

The first portion of your code won't work because you are trying to update a control that was created on the UI thread, so, yes, you will need to use the `Invoke` method.  You cannot update UI controls that were created on the UI thread from another thread.